# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $ when running JasmineHeadlessWebkit

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery, jasmine-headless-webkit

I've been trying to find an answer to this at least for the last two hours without any luck.  I hope someone here might be able to help.

I'm getting this `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $` when running my Jasmine specs using the JasmineHeadlessWebkit.

The weird thing is, this only happens when I say

```
$ ->
  game.init()
```

in my `game.coffee` file.

I can use the `$` without any problems further down `game.coffee`. For example:

```
window.game =
  init: ->
    $('.gamelayer').hide()
    $('#gamestartscreen').show()
```

This is no problem at all.

Also, the tests work okay in Chrome.

So, I'm assuming this has to do with jQuery not being loaded in time but I can't figure out why.

I have jQuery in `specs/javascripts/helpers/` and in `jasmine.yml` i'm mentioning the `helpers` before the `spec_files` and `src_files` but that doesn't seem to really make a difference.

So, if anyone has any idea how I can make sure that jQuery is completely loaded when Jasmine's specs are run, I would really appreciate any help.

Also, please let me know if you need any additional information.

Thank you.

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that jQuery is not included at that point in the code. Are you including jQuery before that script?

Answer (score 0):

you can try two solution:

the first one delay the game.init() waiting for jQuery to be loaded:

```
function initJQuery() {
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
        setTimeout("initJQuery()", 50);
    } else {
        game.init();
    }
}
```

the second one calls a jQuery function that prevent conflicts with the library (run it at the beginning of your code):

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

you can try but i'm not sure it's the best solution in your case. Pay attention to use this solution, you'll have to change all '$' to 'jQuery'

Comment: Thanks. The first thing you mentioned works but I consider this more to be a workaround than a real solution. I want to `game.init()` when the document is ready ( `$(document).ready ->` which is long for `$ ->` ), not at some time when jQuery has fully loaded. It should just be loaded and available before `game.coffee` is loaded and calls `$ ->` Thanks for your effort, though!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also. I fixed it by changing my jasmine.yml to load jquery before it loads the rest of the javascript files:

```
src_files:
  - public/js/jquery.js
  - public/js/**/*.js
```